# reload one part of page after clicking button in form asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Good news everyone. I have question, again. I have page with personal information block, personal informaion edit block and pasword block. I need reload only password block after click on button. But I have a problem, when I clicked on button, my page try to reload all page. And requires to again call the method of load personal and password information. But, I need only show message and do things with passwords in password block without affecting personal information block. (Also I need to work with personal information block without affecting password block, but I think it's will be the same answer below).

PersonalInf cotroller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult changePassword(PersonalPageModel personalPage)
    {
        var passwordDetauls = dbModel.USERS.Where(model =>
        model.vPassword == personalPage.usersModel.NewPassword
            ).FirstOrDefault();

        if (passwordDetauls != null)
        {
            personalPage.usersModel.ChangePasswordErrorMessage = "Новый пароль совпадает со старым!";
            return View("~/Views/home/PersonalPage.cshtml", personalPage);
        }
        else
        {
            var userDetails = dbModel.USERS.Where(model =>
            model.vPassword == personalPage.usersModel.vPassword).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                personalPage.usersModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Неверный пароль!";
                return View("~/Views/home/PersonalPage.cshtml", personalPage);
            }
            else
            {
                int iIdUsers = Convert.ToInt32(Session["iIdUsers"].ToString());

                //Change password here!

                var query = from ord in dbModel.USERS
                            where ord.iIdUsers == iIdUsers
                            select ord;

                foreach (var ord in query)
                {
                    ord.vPassword = personalPage.usersModel.NewPassword;
                }

                try
                {
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    personalPage.usersModel.ChangePasswordErrorMessage = exc.Message;
                }

                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Пароль был успешно изменен!";

                //Session["iIdUsers"] = userDetails.iIdUsers;
                //Session["vNickName"] = userDetails.vNickName;
                //return RedirectToAction("PersonalPage", "Home");

                return View("~/Views/home/PersonalPage.cshtml", personalPage);
            }
        }
    }
```

and view code, code like autherize form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("changePersonalInf", "PersonalPage", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Город:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>ФИО:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vFIO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Индекс:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vIndex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Населенный пункт:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vLocality, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Улица:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vStreet, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Дом/корпус/строение:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vHome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Квартира:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vApartment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Телефон:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalInfModel.vPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Изменить" class="btn-problem" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Очистка" class="btn-problem" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the change password block in a partial view and change the form to Ajax form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("changePersonalInf", "PersonalPage", FormMethod.Post)) {

}
```

to

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("changePersonalInf", "PersonalPage", null, new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "id_of_your_change_password_block"
}, new { role = "form", id = "AssignCoachForm" })) {

}
```

This will automatically update the block with the given ID. Alternatively, you can do that by yourself in JavaScript and have more control over it:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("changePersonalInf", "PersonalPage", null, new AjaxOptions {
    OnSuccess = "your_js_success_function(data);",
    OnFailure = "your_js_failure_function();",
}, new { role = "form", id = "AssignCoachForm" })) {

}
```

Comment: It's not working! I again gave problem with null pointer exception. Can you show Me example, how this code will show when I'll change it?

Comment: There are tons of examples online. Try to implement one of them and if you have issues, post your new code (maybe in a new question) so we can help you.